# Adding Scroll in After effects Script UI panel

Tags: plugins, jsx, adobe, after-effects

I created an script using chatGPT and it's functioning fine but when the items are in large number it going beyound view port.

I was woundring how to add scroll in the Script's UI panel. Let me know for any refrences and solutions.